# Defining php classes

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Method chaining Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889208/php-method-chaining-confusion)

If i have a php class

```
class ClassName {
    function f1() {
        //...
    }
    function f2() {
        //...
    }
}
$cn = new ClassName();
```

How to define the class that i can use functions in style

```
$cn->f1()->f2();
```

instead of

```
$cn->f1();
$cn->f2();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
class ClassName {
    public function f1() {
        //...
        return $this;
    }
    public function f2() {
        //...
        return $this;
    }
    // and for a static
    public static function sf1() {
        // ...
        return self;
    }
}
```

But, method chaining is a **bad idea**. It makes for hard to read code.

If you are returning an instance of the same object, it is not directly harmful. But, when you start writing code like `$locator->get('MySQL')->connection()->query('SELECT 1');`, then it is possible that people who are stuck maintaining your code will find where you live and punish you.

Also, if you are going by *"but jquery does it"* reasoning, I am sorry to inform you, but that - more often than not - is a sign that something is a bad practice.

Comment: I think method chaining can be a good idea because it makes certain code easier to read.

Comment: @erisco , in some very specific cases, and if you are sticking to same instance - yes, you are right. But the general rule of thumb is: *"Avoid It"*.

Comment: its very bad.. probably thats why Zend frameworks uses this in all of its setters

Comment: Please cite a discussion that illustrates or otherwise showcases why method chaining should be avoided. I haven't heard of this.

Comment: @mschr , and of course we all know that Zend Framework is such a [collection](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php#L47) [of](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/EventManager/StaticEventManager.php#L51) [best](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Header/CacheControl.php#L177) [practices](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Di/Di.php#L466).

Comment: @erisco , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571009/one-lined-class-functions-do-or-dont

Answer (score 4):

To have chaining in functions you need to **return current object** from the function..

```
return $this;
```

add this in your function `f1()`..

```
class ClassName {
    function f1() {
        //...
        return $this;
    }
    function f2() {
        //...
        return $this;
    }
}
```